# process in the background

Tags: linux, timeout, time, shell-scripting

I have loop in shell script and it takes time process only a few files in the list. How do I push the process in the background and select the next file while the first file is still being processed?

```
   for newfile in `ls new*`
    do
    time consuming process &
    done
```

I tried & at the end of the command after > /dev/null 2>&1 but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put a process in background just put the `&` at the end and remove the `;` you used to terminate the command before `done`

```
for newfile in new* ; do
    long_running_command 2>&1 > /dev/null &
done
```

You don't need the

```
`ls new*`
```

you can just use

```
new*
```

the shell will expand it for you.

Example

```
touch new1
touch new2
for newfile in new* ; do ls $newfile 2>&1 > /dev/null & done
```

produces

```
[1] 92197
[1]+  Done                    ls $newfile 2>&1 > /dev/null
[1] 92198
[1]+  Done                    ls $newfile 2>&1 > /dev/null
```